# FB Marketing API V2.7 deprecation

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

When exactly is the FB marketing API deprecation? 
On FB's developer site they say it's till April. This is the first version in which they don't mention the accurate date - but a month's scope.
Is it deprecated on the 1st of April? at the end of April?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/changelog

Comment: File a bug at developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 1):

We support two versions of Ads API at one time. For now we support v27 and v28. And we are releasing v29 in middle April. At that time v27 will be deprecated.

We encourage all developers to move to newer version of API during the cycle of one release window. If you are using any of SDK we released, you will need to pull a new version of SDK and look at breaking changes. We are trying to make your upgrade experience smooth. Feel free to provide feedback and stories of your upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. looks like FB updated their API versioning page.
The deprecation of v2.7 is on the 25th of April.
Thank you guys for your help.